# remove specific json object from $.cookie

Tags: jquery

I have a simple shopping cart where the user adds products to their cart.  Each added product is saved as an object to a $.cookie .

when a user removes a product, that product object is removed from the cookie or the quantity is dropped by one. updating that objects quantity works ok i believe.

my issue is is that i don't think im using splice correctly, and i cannot figure out how to make this work as a result.  basically what happens is the first product object is always removed from the $.cookie as opposed to that specific object where there is a match being removed.

below is my code.  i'm hoping someone can spot the problem.   i suspect it's the "1" (first element) that's causing the issue >>  current_objs.splice(current_objs[i],1)

here is my code.

```
$('body').on('click', '.remove_me', function(e) {

  var productid = $(this).data('productid');

  var current_objs = $.cookie("obj");

  for (i = 0; i < current_objs.length; i++) {

    if (current_objs[i].productid === productid.toString()) {

      if (current_objs[i].qty == 1) {

        current_objs.splice(current_objs[i],1);          

        $.cookie("obj",current_objs, { path: '/' });

      } else {

        current_objs[i].qty = current_objs[i].qty - 1;

        $.cookie("obj",current_objs, { path: '/' });
      }

    }

  }

});
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of `current_objs.splice(current_objs[i],1); ` try `current_objs.splice(i,1); `.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript `array.splice()` has the following parameters:

```
array.splice(index, howMany, item1, item2, .., itemN)
```

Where

- `index` is the index in array to add/remove items.
- `howMany` is the number of elements to be removed.
- `item1-N` are items to be added.

Try this instead:

```
current_objs.splice(i, 1); // remove 1 item and index i
```